# Simplify express routing with n folders in partials

Tags: node.js, express

I'm doing some routing with Express, but I can't  find a way to achieve this more efficiently.

For example, in my node script to init the app, I need to declare each route like:

```
// server.js
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('/partials/session/:name', routes.sessionpartials);
```

And then:

```
// routes.js
    exports.partials = function (req, res) {
      var name = req.params.name;
      res.render('partials/' + name);
    };

    exports.sessionpartials = function (req, res) {
      var name = req.params.name;
      res.render('partials/session/' + name);
    };
```

So I have access to `/partials` and `/partials/session`, but If i create another folder inside `/partials` without declaring it, isn't going to be available.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your URL routes and your partial paths are a 1:1 relationship, then you can just do something like this:

```
app.get('/partials/*', routes.partials);
```

And then:

```
exports.partials = function (req, res) {
  res.render(req.path.slice(1));
};
```

Comment: What if I need to render a .jade template in /partials/folder1/ ?

Comment: If you navigate to myapp.com/partials/folder/whatever, req.path will resolve to /partials/folder/whatever  which would presumably resolve to the filename and path of your jade template (actually you need to call slice() to strip out the first forward slash, I've updated my answer).